# LibreOffice: Print paragraph marks and numbers

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I can see that it is possible to view the paragraph symbol in Libreoffice, but I also need it it print.

I need to print the paragraph symbol followed by the number of that paragraph, starting from 1. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - but the implementation depends on the content of your document. The easiest way to insert a paragraph sign (¶) and a number is **using the numbering feature, setting the ¶ as text to put before each number**. This works only if your document doesn't contain any other numbering yet.

If there's already auto-numbered text, you'll will have to use a table to separate numbering from main text.

If you only have plain text in your document without numbering, just edit the "`Default Style`" paragraph style of your document to use numbering (for example numbering style "`Numbering 1`"),

[image]

[image]

and then edit the numbering style:

[image]

[image]

### EDIT:

To adapt the position so tabs don't indent the numbering, you'll have to set the appropriate values in the numbering style's position settings. Using the following setting (notice the selection 1-10 in the left list box), there's no difference between the different levels:

[image]

If you want to indent only the text but not the numbering / paragraph symbol, yoou would have to set the tab stop / indent value as desired (for every level).

Comment: One question: Now when I tab over, it moves the numbering. I want the numbering to stay all aligned with the left margin. How do I do this?